# mysql process stopping install as cannot kill

Tags: server, mysql, process, mariadb

I am trying to install `mariadb` but install exits as fail as `Mysql` is running and it cannot stop.

MySql is not installed but there is a process running which I cannot kill

```
root@sonic-ubuntu ~ # ps aux | grep mysql
root      8639  0.0  0.0   9496  2244 pts/0    S+   08:55   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

When i try to kill it respawns with a different PID
I have tried to identify what is starting the process using `ptree` but it isn't showing up.

Running Ubuntu 15.10

Any help appreciated.

Okay if i try and install mariadb i get the following

```
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.12+maria-1~wily_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.12+maria-1~wily_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_10.1.12+maria-1~wily_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (10.1.12+maria-1~wily) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.1_10.1.12+maria-1~wily_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Which suggests mysql is running

yes but i cant find or stop it!

Answer (score 1):

The output of `ps aux | grep ...` will naturally contain the `grep` process itself:

```
root 8639 0.0 0.0 9496 2244 pts/0 S+ 08:55 0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

There seems to be no instance of MySQL running on the system in question.

Comment: okay...when i try to install mariadb i get the following